# Javacv Face Recognition

Tags: opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I'm trying to use FaceRecognition with javacv. But when I have more than 5 train images I get this error:

> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   #
>   #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6a30b400, pid=4856, tid=32
>   #
>   # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
>   # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
>   # Problematic frame:
>   # C  [opencv_core246.dll+0x4b400]
>   #
>   # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>   #
>   # An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   # C:\Users\reco\workspace\hellow\hs_err_pid4856.log
>   #
>   # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>   #

This is my code:

```java
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class OpenCVFaceRecognizer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String trainingDir = "C:/Users/reco/workspace/hellow";

    IplImage testImage = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/reco/workspace/0.png");

    File root = new File(trainingDir);

    FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
        }
    };

    File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

     MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

    int counter = 0;
    int label;

    IplImage img;
    IplImage grayImg;

    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath());
        String temp= image.getName();
        label = Integer.parseInt(temp.charAt(0)+"");

        grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        images.put(counter, grayImg);

        labels[counter] = label;

        counter++;
    }

    IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
     FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

    faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

    cvCvtColor(testImage, greyTestImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);

    System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
}
}
```

edit::i just removed

```
    grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

and it worked :)

Comment: Please post your solution an an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    IplImage img;
    IplImage grayImg=null;

    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath(),CV_BGR2GRAY);
        int yer = image.getName().indexOf(".");
        String isim=image.getName().substring(0,yer);

        label = Integer.parseInt(isim);

        images.put(counter, img);

        labels[counter] = label;

        counter++;
    }
```

it is the final of my code and it works like a charm :)